# what is the difference between import Task and import { Task } in es6

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

What is the difference between

```
import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';
```

and

```
import Task from './Task.jsx';
```

when to use `{}` and when to not use `{}` ?

(by the way, this is from meteor tutorial https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/update-and-remove)

Comment: Within the braces you can import multiple classes and methods.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use the {} when you precise that it's a default export.

For example :

```
export default class Test{}
```

You can do :

```
import Test from './test'
```

In the other hand, if you don't precise "default" keyword, you have to precise {} :

```
export class Test {}
```

gives

```
import { Test } from './test'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to grab the all modules you can do

```
import * as test from "Test";
```

If you exporting only some modules and not all then you have to specify wictch module you want

```
import { Module1, Module2, Module3 } from "Modules"; //grab only given in {}
```

if you have only `export default Test` you can to

```
import "Test";
```

[read more about modules](http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html)

Answer (score 0):

when you do

```
 import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';
```

you are importing Task module from '../api/tasks.js';

when you do

```
import Tasks  from '../api/tasks.js';
```

you are importing default export module from '../api/tasks.js'; Here Task is a variable which is referring default export module.

Example.

task.js
    export default Task;

case 1: It is Task from task.js
case 2: It is Task variable pointing to Task module in task.js that is Task

if I do
import someVariable from './api/task.js' still it will work because someVarible will point to default export module that is Task module in task.js

If I do

import {someVariable} from './api/task.js' it will search for module someVariable in task.js but it is not there so now it is undefined.